# Proving an inequality $\frac{x^2}{y+z}+\frac{y^2}{x+z}+\frac{z^2}{y+x}>\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)$, for $x,y,z>0$

Tags: inequality

I'm having trouble proving the following inequality:

$\frac{x^2}{y+z}+\frac{y^2}{x+z}+\frac{z^2}{y+x}\geq\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)$, for $x,y,z>0$

There is an equality case, which is where $x=y=z$. Then assume without loss of generality that $x>y>z$. By combining the fractions, we get $\frac{x^2(x+z)+y^2(y+z)(x+y)+z^2(y+z)(x+z)}{(y+z)(x+z)(x+y)}>\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{(2z)^2(2x)}$.

I have no idea if this is at all useful and I would be very grateful for some hints.

Comment: Yes, I think it does

Answer (score 1):

By Schwarz:
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{y+z}+\frac{y^2}{z+x}+\frac{z^2}{x+y}\right)((y+z)+(z+x)+(x+y)) \ge (x+y+z)^2.$$